# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier using Submit Handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I am Creating validation script and ajax call. I face the  problem is that

> alert message is not working in if condition

I can't figure out what's going on here, when I run the script, in Chrome it says:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Below is my code :

```
  $("#myCA-Form").validate({

    rules:{
    field1:"required",
    city:"required",
    email:{
    required:true,
    email:true
    },
    phone:{
    required:true,
    number: true,
    minlength:9,
    maxlength:10
    }
    },

    messages:{
    name:"Please enter your username..!",
    email:"Please enter your email..!",
    phone:"Enter your mobile no"
    },


    submitHandler: function(form) {


    var formData =  $(form).serialize();
    var id = $('#product_id2').val();

    var name = $('#field1').val();
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://eaxmple.co.in/test.aspx?"+formData,
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,  
    data: {formd : formData },
    success: function(data) {
     }


    });
     if(id=='100105')
    {
    alert("sdfsd");
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML='submit Successfully!!!';
     }

    }

  });
```

Comment: Normally there is a line where the error occurred. Could you share that too and mark it in your code? ... btw i would leave out the "Please Help me ASAP."

Comment: Please post some more information such as HTML code, debugging result, Console error.....

Comment: There is no problem in your code. its working perfectly. I hope the problem is somewhere other

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your code. its working perfectly. I hope the problem is somewhere other

This is the exact copy of your code, with added HTML code

```js
$("#myCA-Form").validate({

    rules:{
    field1:"required",
    city:"required",
    email:{
    required:true,
    email:true
    },
    phone:{
    required:true,
    number: true,
    minlength:9,
    maxlength:10
    }
    },

    messages:{
    name:"Please enter your username..!",
    email:"Please enter your email..!",
    phone:"Enter your mobile no"
    },


    submitHandler: function(form) {


    var formData =  $(form).serialize();
    var id = $('#product_id2').val();

    var name = $('#field1').val();
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://eaxmple.co.in/test.aspx?"+formData,
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,  
    data: {formd : formData },
    success: function(data) {
     }


    });
     if(id=='11')
    {
    alert("sdfsd");
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML='submit Successfully!!!';
     }

    }

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id="myCA-Form">
 <input name="field1" type="text"/>
 <input name="city" type="text"/>
 <input name="email" type="text"/>
 <input name="phone" type="text"/>
 <input value="11" id="product_id2" type="hidden"/>
<button class="save-post">Save Post</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not append formdata to the URL, if you want something like that you should be looking at GET method instead of POST. You might wanna read more about POST and GET.